# Weyl group action on maximal torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, group-actions, classifying-spaces

This is a classical result in the theory of Lie groups, but I am stuck on trying to understand the action of the Weyl group on the classifying space of the torus. Namely,

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie Group and $T$ be a maximal torus in $G$. Let $W = N(T)/T$ be the Weyl group of $T$ in $G$. This groups acts on $T$ by conjugation (the action is well defined as $T$ is abelian) and so it induces an action on the classifying space $BT$.

This is the argument that I still do not completely get

> Mimura M, Toda H. Topology of Lie groups, I and II. American Mathematical Soc.; 1991.

Let $p: BT \rightarrow BG$ be the map induced by the inclusion, and $f_n : BT \rightarrow BT$ the map induced by the conjugation of $nT \in W$. Then $f_n(eT) = enT$ for $e \in ET$ and so $$(p\circ f_n)(eT) = p(enT) = p(enG) = eG = p(eT)$$ 
Therefore, $p^*(H^*(BG)) \subseteq H^*(BT)^W$

It is not clear for me why the conjugation action induces the map $f_n$ defined above. I'd appreciate if someone has an insight of how to compute the map out of the action.

Comment: What do you already know about classifying spaces?  The existence of $f_n$ is coming from the more general fact that a homomorphism a between Lie groups induces a map between their classifying spaces.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I know that. My question is why specifically the  map $f_n$ is given by that when it comes from conjugation; this is crucial to show that (the image of) $H^*(BG)$ is invariant under the action of $W$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how Toda computed the map $f_n$, but here is an alternate proof that $p^\ast(H^\ast(BG))\subseteq H^\ast(BT)^W$.  I found the proof [in the notes of Dwyer and Wilkerson](https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/Elementary.Lie.Groups.pdf)

Let $n\in N(T)$ and consider the function $c_n:G\rightarrow G$ which is conjugation by $n$.  Because there is a path in $G$ from $n$ to the identity, we see that the induced map $c_n:BG\rightarrow BG$ is homotopic to the identity, and hence, that $c_n^\ast: H^\ast(BG)\rightarrow H^\ast(BG)$ is the identity map.

Now, consider the following commutative diagram. $$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
T & \ra{i} & G \\
\da{c_n|_T} & & \da{c_n} \\
T & \ras{i} & G  \\
\end{array}$$

This diagram induces another commutitive diagram. $$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
H^\ast(BG) & \ra{p^\ast} & H^\ast(BT) \\
\da{c_n^\ast} & & \da{(c_n|_T)^\ast} \\
H^\ast(BG) & \ras{p^\ast} & H^\ast(BT)  \\
\end{array}$$

We have already argued that $c_n^\ast$ is the identity.  So, $(c_n|_T)^\ast p^\ast = p^\ast$.

In other words, each $n\in N(T)$ acts trivially on the image of $p^\ast$.  Thus, all of $W = N(T)/T$ acts trivially on the image of $p^\ast$ so $p^\ast(H^\ast(BG))\subseteq H^\ast(BT)^W$.